# Linear maps, proof the equivalence of the following statments.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $V$ be a Vectorspace with dimension $n$, and $L:V\rightarrow V$ a linear map. Show that:

$$\mathrm{im}(L) = \ker(L)\iff 
L^2=0, n\text{ is even and }\dim(\mathrm{im}(L))=\frac{n}{2}$$

Comment: $T=L$? Please show what you've tried and ask a specific question where you are stuck. (a) You should show some effort. (b) We have no idea what you know and what you do not know, so by telling us what you know and what you're trying, that helps a little.

Comment: My mistake T = L, my problem with this question is, if my image equals my kernel, doesn't that mean my image is only the zero-vector and therfore n/2 for the dimension of the image makes no sense.

Comment: How did you get to "my image is only $0$"?

Comment: if **im(L)=ker(L)** than every member of the image is an member of the kernel, and therfore gets mapped to zero.

Comment: ($\Rightarrow$) Take $x\in V$, then $Lx\in \operatorname{im}(L)=\operatorname{ker}(L)$. Therefore, $L^2x=L(Lx)=0$. Therefore, $L^2$ is the zero operator. From the rank-nullity theorem $n=\operatorname{dim}(V)=\operatorname{dim}(\operatorname{im}(L))+\operatorname{dim}(\operatorname{ker}(L))=2\operatorname{dim}(\operatorname{im}(L))$. Therefore, $\operatorname{dim}(\operatorname{im}(L))=n/2$.

Comment: ($\Leftarrow$) If $L^2=0$, then for all $v\in\operatorname{im}(L)$ there is $x\in V$ such that $v=Lx$. Then $Lv=L^2x=0$. So $\operatorname{im}(L)\subset\operatorname{ker}(L)$. Now, from the rank-nullity theorem $\operatorname{dim}(\operatorname{ker}(L))=n-\operatorname{dim}(\operatorname{im}(L))=n/2=\operatorname{dim}(\operatorname{im}(L))$. Therefore, $\operatorname{im}(L)=\operatorname{ker}(L)$

Comment: Note that the kernel is the vectors that are sent to zero by $L$. They are not necessarily zero already before $L$ is applied on them. Your argument somehow makes my think that you confused these two ideas in your mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume for "$\Rightarrow$" that the image and kernel of $L$ are the same. Then, $L^2=0$ because for any $v\in V$, you have $w:=L(v)\in\operatorname{im}(L)=\ker(L)$, so $L^2(v)=L(L(v))=L(w)=0$. As $v$ was arbitrary, $L^2=0$. By the rank-nullity theorem, you also have
$$
n = \dim(V) = \dim(\operatorname{im}(L)) + \dim(\ker(L)) = 2\cdot\dim(\operatorname{im}(L)),
$$
which implies the statement.

For the other direction, first note that $L^2=0$ implies $\operatorname{im}(L)\subseteq\ker(L)$. From
$$
n = \dim(V) = \dim(\operatorname{im}(L)) + \dim(\ker(L)) = \frac{n}{2} + \dim(\ker(L)),
$$
it also follows that $\dim(\ker(L))=n-\frac{n}{2}=\frac{n}{2}=\dim(\operatorname{im}(L))$ and so we are done.

*In case this last implication is unclear: Pick any basis of $\operatorname{im}(L)$; this basis is contained in $\ker(L)$ and so it is also a basis of $\ker(L)$ because it remains linearly independent and its cardinality is equal to the dimension of $\ker(L)$. As the two spaces share a basis, $\operatorname{im}(L)$ and $\ker(L)$ are the same.